# Pycharm install package error

Tags: python, package, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install the wxPython package using Pycharm's Project Interpreter on my mac.  I have been able to install other packages in the past, but with this package I get an error:

[image]

Any ideas?  I've checked, and I have both read and write permissions to both the ./pip and ./pip/http directories, and pip is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead.

Once brew is installed, just type 'brew install wxpython' in your terminal to install wxPython.

Comment: Installed homebrew, then installed wxpython with it.  home-brew said it worked, but when I try to import it in Pycharm it says there is no such module.